# How I print all pages of my report with crystal report and c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

```
REPORT.CR_CoustomerAccount CR = new REPORT.CR_CoustomerAccount(); 
CR.SetParameterValue("@From", dtpFromDate.Text);
CR.SetParameterValue("@To", dtpToDate.Text);
CR.SetParameterValue("@Cus_ID", Cus_ID);
CR.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "Canon MG2500 series Printer";
CR.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 1, 1);
```

The upper code is to print report directly without getting through CrystalReportViewer, the problem is the total of pages in this report is 3 Pages and the upper code print **only a first page**, but if i print the report through the CrystalReportViewer it's will print the Report completely with all its' pages,

What i want is to using the print method to print all pages directly without Getting through the CrystalReportViewer.

Comment: Someone help me please

Comment: Maybe it's too late: PrintToPrinter(int nCopies, bool collated, int startPageN, int endPageN) so if it's 3 pages it should be: CR.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 1, 3);